# Clustering algorithm for rectangular region detection

Tags: clustering

I have a Cartesian grid (with integer coordinates) that contains some samples. The total number of samples on the grid is expected to be in the millions, but the grid can extend upwards of  a million units in any direction, so it still contains a lot of empty space.

Essentially, my problem is: given a list of (x, y) coordinates of the samples, find an arbitrary (but sensible) number of regions of close-together samples on the grid, where the regions are horizontally rectangular (i.e. each region could be its own small PNG image without the need for rotation).

I have a constant-sized-chunk approach to this already implemented, but I wanted to try a clustering-based solution too, which I'm hoping will give better results. I'm looking through the various algorithms offered by [`scipy`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html), but I don't really see an obvious stand-out. Basically, I would need a clustering algorithm that:

- works with a large number of samples;
- does not require a predefined number of clusters (the number of clusters is expected to be in the tens or possibly in the hundreds);
- allows a distance metric that favours horizontally rectangular cluster shapes (e.g. Chebyshev distance);
- works with uneven cluster sizes (in terms of both number of samples and distance);
- handles outliers (i.e. considers a single outlier to be its own cluster, but still groups together multiple outliers if they are close together).

This is a rough sketch of what I'd ideally want from my algorithm (with each colour representing a distinct cluster):

[image]

Just with a lot more total samples and more clusters (and potentially much more vast areas of empty space). The purple cluster at the bottom right could acceptably also be split into two rectangular clusters.

What would be an appropriate clustering algorithm to use in this case?